# Editing and deleting events in fullcalendar v4

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

I want to use ajax to edit events and delete events using full calendar but for some reason it doesn't work. I think it's a slight issue with my code and I would like some help in fixing it.

This is for PHP using fullcalendar v4, mySQL, AJAX, Javascript

```
   eventDrop: function (info) {
                var start = moment(info.event.start).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var end = moment(info.event.end).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var title = info.event.title;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'edit-event.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { start: start, end: end, title : title },
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (response) {
                        calendar.fullCalendar( info.event.title);
                        //Above is the proper way to reference what I am posting with AJAX
                        displayMessage("Updated Successfully");
                    }
                });
            },

            eventClick: function (info) {
                var deleteMsg = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
                if (deleteMsg) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'delete-event.php',

                        data: { title : title },
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (parseInt(response) > 0) {
                                calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', info.event.title);//call the 'removeEvents' built in function and reference "var title"
                                displayMessage("Deleted Successfully");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
```

## edit-event.php

```
include "dbconnect.php";

if(isset($_POST['title'])){

$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

  $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE events_table SET start='" . $start . "',end='" . $end . "' WHERE title= '$title' ";

  $conn->query($sqlUpdate);
 }
 $conn->close();
```

## delete-event.php

```
 include "dbconnect.php";

 if(isset($_POST['title'])){
 $title = $_POST['title'];

 echo $sqlDelete = "DELETE from events_table WHERE title='$title'";


 mysqli_query($conn, $sqlDelete);
 echo mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
 }
```

I expect it to on click remove the event 
.Then when it is dragged and droped it should update on the database.

Comment: where does `$_POST['title']` come from, it's not sent with your AJAX request?

Comment: I don't need it actually since it's drag and drop the events but update on the database, was experimenting editing on click

Comment: Specifically what part (or parts) is not working? And what does that mean exactly? What error or unexpected behaviour are you seeing? Have you attempted any debugging to try and narrow down the problem?

Comment: If you are using fullCalendar v4 then I'm pretty sure `$.fullCalendar.formatDate` won't work since fullCalendar doesn't use jQuery any more. Any errors in your console.

Comment: Also your SQL queries are vulnerable to injection attacks. Please look up how to use parameterised queries and prepared statements to protect your database. http://bobby-tables.com has a good explanation of the risk and also a simple page showing how to write queries safely using PHP/mySQLi. Never trust data coming into your server from outside... always sanitise it

Comment: @ADyson that is a big help, will look up and adjust my queries! and it just wasn't updating on the database and the person below explained why. It was bad implementation.

Comment: It's the same as one of the things I mentioned above. And that didn't _directly_ cause it to not insert into the database - that was a secondary symptom. The code crashed long before it got to that point. The primary symptom would have been a JavaScript error in the browser's console. That's what I mean by narrowing down the problem - you think the problem is it failing to add to the database, but in fact the database related code is not the problem, the real issue is in a different place earlier in the process.

Comment: If you get the hang of debugging and investigating the details you'll soon start fixing this sort of stuff yourself. Anyway glad the various suggestions have helped you sort it out

Comment: Ahh i've taken note and it is more clearer. Thank you!

Comment: @ADyson I tried making my queries injection proof but it caused a lot of errors especially when I redid my connection. The functions still don't work for some reason

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question about it, shownig the new version of the code, and explaining the exact error messages you are seeing. Then we'll be able to help you more easily. If you tag me in a comment and link me to the question I'll take a look when I have a moment

Comment: I am not getting any error the function just doesn't work when I do it and I'm confused on how to get around it.

Comment: There is probably some sort of error or unexpected result somewhere, but you just aren't finding it. Do you understand how to debug your JavaScript and PHP code?

Comment: Like I said, ask a whole new question about it with the changed code. But first, do some investigation, try and isolate the issue to a specific few lines of code.

Comment: I don't understand how to debug javascript , i'm really new to it

Comment: @ADyson I have fixed it now

Answer (score 2):

As you are using fullcalendar V4, you cannot use $.fullCalendar because V4 is pure javascript (i.e plain js/vanilla js) as @ADYson mentioned in the comment V4 doesn't use jQuery anymore.

Secondly V4's FullCalendar.formatDate( date, settings ) have different implementation altogether, you can check all the options [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/formatDate).

For that reason you can use moments format() function as follows,

e.g

```
var start = moment(info.event.start).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Here you get desired format in start i.e "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", make sure you have moment js.

Full code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='../packages/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='../packages/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='../packages/core/main.js'></script>
    <script src='../packages/interaction/main.js'></script>
    <script src='../packages/daygrid/main.js'></script>
    <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid'],
                defaultDate: '2019-04-12',
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: '2019-04-01'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: '2019-04-07',
                        end: '2019-04-10'
                    },
                    {
                        groupId: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: '2019-04-09T16:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        groupId: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: '2019-04-16T16:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Conference',
                        start: '2019-04-11',
                        end: '2019-04-13'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: '2019-04-12T10:30:00',
                        end: '2019-04-12T12:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: '2019-04-12T12:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: '2019-04-12T14:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Happy Hour',
                        start: '2019-04-12T17:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Dinner',
                        start: '2019-04-12T20:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: '2019-04-13T07:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        url: 'http://google.com/',
                        start: '2019-04-28'
                    }
                ],
                eventDrop: function (info) {
                    var start = moment(info.event.start).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = moment(info.event.start).format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'edit-event.php',
                        data: { start: start, end: end, id: id },
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (response) {
                            displayMessage("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });
                },

                eventClick: function (info) {
                    var deleteMsg = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
                    if (deleteMsg) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'delete-event.php',
                            data: { id: id },
                            success: function (response) {
                                if (parseInt(response) > 0) {
                                    info.event.remove(); 
                                    displayMessage("Deleted Successfully");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            calendar.render();
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, i see what you mean and yes I have moment js plugged in. will try it noe

Comment: I tried out the above but it seems it is still not working for me, so i was wondering if it is the queries i'm using? I got errors trying to change up my queries any further.

Comment: @DokuboWhyte you have `data: { id: id }` please post full js code, I was wondering where is `id` coming from.

Comment: I think that is the issue as well so I changed that, will post the full code now

Comment: Lot of bugs, you are using jQuery statements, but you dont have jQuery included, why are you deleting events against id if you are updating it against title? id variable is not defined in js,

Comment: I realised that, but I decided to try and fix the edit first and that is how I updated against title in the edit bit. even though I am updating against title it doesn't work. If I can get the edit working I can easily sort out the delete. I think the only Jquery is in the two functions I am trying to fix but I really can't tell the difference. Could you help pointing it out?